# Has anyone encountered (and resolved) the force close issue with Google Music Beta App?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, google-play-music

I was very happy to receive a Google Music Beta invite recently.  Unfortunately, when I try to play music via the app (on Droid X rooted with Liberty GB 0.5) the application force closes every time.  I am aware that since this is in beta, there may be no fix available yet, but I figured that I would ask the question and hope for the best.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this issue was related to the ROM.  Since multiple re-installs of the app did not correct the issue, experimenting with another ROM (Apex 2.0 beta) did the trick.  After flashing the new ROM and installing the app, music streams quite well.

Update: I have learned that the Liberty Toolbox > Liberty Tweaks > Ad Blocker feature being set to "Block most ads" has been tracked down as the root cause of this issue.  Make sure to "Enable ads" under this setting and there should not be anymore FC issues.